# Vaadin Upload component in Binder, e.g. Crud editor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Crud (From Vaadin Pro) and would like to use the upload component in BinderCrudEditor. The Upload component doesn't store a value (or rather the HasValue interface is missing), so I can't use the Binder. Is there any way to include it somehow without creating an extra button in Crud for file upload and then working with listeners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is perhaps to use `CustomField` of Vaadin framework. What you need to actually decide is the return type. Also setting the value of the field is a bit awkward use case depending how you have selected the return type. So thus take this more as pseudocode example.

```
public class UploadField extends CustomField<InputStream> {

    InputStream is;
    FileBuffer buffer = new FileBuffer();
    
    public UploadField() {
        Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
        upload.setAcceptedFileTypes("image/jpeg");
        upload.setMaxFiles(1);
        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
            is = buffer.getInputStream();
        });

        add(upload);            
    }
    
    public String getFileName() {
        return buffer.getFileName();
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream generateModelValue() {
        return is;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setPresentationValue(InputStream newPresentationValue) {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I used Tatu's example and it works well but I now have an issue with the CRUD component - in the CRUD form that pops up when editing an entry the upload field always preserves the last uploaded file, unless I remove it by clicking on the X in the upload field. Clicking the X triggers a file-abort event which removes the file from the upload. 
I would like to reset / clear the upload field every time the CRUD from pops up. 
The binder is linked to the custom upload field using the bind(HasValue<FIELDVALUE> field, ValueProvider<BEAN,FIELDVALUE> getter, Setter<BEAN,FIELDVALUE> setter) method.

Comment: You can use `upload.getElement().setPropertyJson("files", Json.createArray());` to clear the files.

Comment: Thanks, Tatu. That worked great. I tried doing upload.getElement().callJsFunction("customFuction"); where customFuction was defined in vaadin-upload.js but didn't quite managed to do what I wanted.